# Incorrect Autolayout warnings with Xcode

Tags: xcode, autolayout, warnings

I'm trying to use the iAd framework. I added an (off-screen) ADBannerView to my scene which will reveal/hide in response to the bannerViewDidLoadAd: and bannerView:didFailToReceiveAdWithError: methods.

I have four constraints for the ADBannerView:

1. Ad Banner.leading = leading
2. Ad Banner.trailing = trailing
3. View Above.bottom = Ad Banner.top
4. Height = 50

When I look at the Size Inspector for Ad Banner, I have: x = 0, y = 600 (off-screen), Width=600 (full width), height = 50.

For some reason, the Document Outline gives me a warning.

"Ad Banner
Expected: width=600, height=50
Actual: width=480, height=66"

When I run the app, it behaves the way I want it to and it's actually the full-width of the device, but I'm curious why it's giving me warnings....

Any ideas?